# How to limit the result of simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php

I have this code working fine, but the result is unlimited. How to limit the result?

```
<form action="<?php  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword"  required>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["keyword"]) && $_POST['keyword'] !== "") {    
$alphas1 = range('A', 'Z');    
$alphas2 = range('A', 'Z');    
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];    
foreach ($alphas1 as $a1) {        foreach ($alphas2 as $a2) {            
$xml = simplexml_load_file(utf8_encode("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=$keyword.' '.$a1.$a2"));            
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {                               
foreach ($child->suggestion->attributes() as $dta) {                                        

echo $dta.", ";                                   
 }            }                    }    }} ?>
```

Comment: What does it mean - __unlimited__?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Limit in what way? If you only need to display certain info use a filtering algorthim or use an if statement to only print certain data, eg `if($dta=="something"){ echo "something"; }`

Comment: Please format your code properly, even if you don't care (but you should), at least for the people who try to help you

Comment: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=test produces ten results? an XML file becomes invalid if you only read the first half, You need the closing tags and can not merely chop them off. You need to change the number of results via your request to the server.

Comment: It says this after running the code `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\share\mathew.php on line 24`

Comment: After running the code it says "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\share\mathew.php on line 24, kindly help